# Is anything being done to honor Gene Cernan today? (14 Dec. 2017)

Tags: apollo-program, lunar-landing, history

14 December 1972 05:40:56 UTC

US astronaut Gene Cernan returned to the Apollo 17 Lunar Excursion Module, becoming "the last man on the Moon" for forty-five years, so far.  (as reported in my [Space History](http://www.l5development.com/i_resource/history/DayInHistory.php?d=1214) newsletter)

It seems like there should be something done to honor the man who had that dubious title foisted upon him:  I'm sure he didn't expect that to be an accurate description when he passed away on 16 January this past year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On that particular date, a cargo spacecraft called the *S.S. Gene Cernan* was in orbit after completing a supply mission to the International Space Station.  The Cygnus-class spacecraft was built by Orbital ATK; [launched](https://www.spaceflightinsider.com/organizations/orbital-sciences-corp/we-shall-return-s-s-gene-cernan-lifts-off-from-mars-pad-0a/) from Wallops Island on November 12, 2017; docked with the ISS carrying [3338 kg of cargo](https://spaceflight101.com/cygnus-oa8/cargo-overview/); and left the ISS on December 6 with 2900 kg of trash.  It then spent nearly two weeks deploying cubesats and performing an experiment called SAFFIRE which lit the largest intentional fire in space.  The vessel [burned up in the atmosphere](https://spaceflight101.com/iss/cygnus-cargo-spacecraft-ends-successful-mission-after-extended-free-flight-demonstration/) over New Zealand on December 18.

Cernan was a critic of the Commercial Resupply Services program for the ISS, so it is somewhat ironic that such a spacecraft was named after him.

I haven't found him anywhere else in the news on that date; he died earlier in the year on January 16.  Keep in mind that a 45th anniversary is not as notable as a round number such as the 50th.

Comment: I wonder if the timing of the mission was planned such that the _S.S. Gene Cernan_ would be in space on the 14 December anniversary, or if it was just coincidence.  I suspect we're going to see that "round number" 50th anniversary without more "boots on the ground" on the Moon, which is a disappointment, in and of itself...